# How to solve OS module path error in Python

Tags: python, module

I started python from last week. I am just learning modules, and using os module i wrote a program that would ask user the disk drive they want to access and prints all the folders inside that drive, and again ask user to select a folder among them and access that folder and the process repeats . It worked alright but it only accessed top level directory and one directory inside it. After that error occurs saying that the path does not exist, but infact path shown in error message is valid.Help me out please.
my program is:

```
import os
def fun(path1,path2):
    p1=os.path.join(path1,path2)
    os.chdir(p1)
    print('currently in ',p1)
    print('folders currently in this directories are:')
    print(next(os.walk('.'))[1])
    p2=input('which folder you wanna access among these:')
    fun(p1,p2)
x=input('which drive you wanna access:')
fun(x,path2='')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `os.chdir()`, otherwise the relative path `p1` will not work outside of the initial working directory.

Explanation: suppose you start in `/home/you`, and you want to reach `/home/you/some/folder`. At the first step you choose `some`, the current directory changes to `/home/you/some`, then you choose `folder`, which gets concatenated with some, so from directory `/home/you/some` you try to `chdir()` into `some/folder` which does not exist.

Pass `p1` to `os.walk()` instead:

```
def fun(path1,path2):
    p1=os.path.join(path1,path2)
    print('currently in ',p1)
    print('folders currently in this directories are:')
    print(next(os.walk(p1))[1])
    p2=input('which folder you wanna access among these:')
    fun(p1,p2)
```

Comment: without os.chdir(), is it possible to access directories other than intial one?...i tried and it got stuck on the initial directory only and showed folders only from initial directory :(

Comment: it finally worked after i removed chdir and changed print(next(os.walk('.'))[1]) to print(next(os.walk(p1))[1])..thanks but still i did not get how it worked